# npm how do I patch/bump my node package up to version 1.0.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I have some node packages and I keep patching each version and then publishing

`npm version patch`

=> 0.0.1

`npm publish`

**now do some **

`npm version patch`

=> 0.0.2

`npm publish`

Assume I now want to jump up to version 1.0.0, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`version`'s docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version):

```
npm version major
```

Or you could always just edit package.json.